# Is this a legitimate way to vertically+horizontally center images in HTML?

Tags: css

I came across the following technique to vertically center an image inside a DIV element.

```
<div>
    <img src="someimage.png" />
</div>

div {
    position:relative;
    width:400px;
    height:300px;
    border: solid 1px #cccccc;
}

img {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    margin: auto;
}
```

Created a fiddle for it here: http://jsfiddle.net/MryZv/1/

I didn't find any tip on the web directing to this technique.

Is there a caveat I'm missing? Is it "safe" for use?

Comment: You can use `display:table-cell` to align the content vertical without _absolute positioning_. [Example](http://jsfiddle.net/vucko/MryZv/2/)

Comment: @Vucko, the technique shown in the question works and I love it. I am asking why no-one mentions it ever when discussing vertical centering? Does it not works sometimes?

Comment: I would say that you have to be certain that the image is smaller than the div; that is, you don't have any resizing there.

Comment: Absolute positioning inside relative element is a well spread method. I see it being used all the time. I think you are safe.

Comment: @vals Good point. max-width + max-height should be added to the img element.

Comment: It doesn't, like many things, work in older IEs IIRC. For such a simple case, there are several different vertical align methods available. It probably just doesn't bring anything new to the table.

Comment: I don't like it because you aren't specifying the width/height of the image. When I need to vertically center images, I just use a margin-top: #px; inline style generated by the server for dynamically sized images. Is that standardized? No, but 100% foolproof. Also, making it a background image with center center declaration works like a charm.

Comment: @ProfileTwist The image I need to center is returned by an API call (the size of it is unknown). I know background image works, but this technique is semantically better.

Comment: Here are some articles covering this technique: http://www.vanseodesign.com/css/vertical-centering/ | http://www.student.oulu.fi/~laurirai/www/css/middle/ | http://blog.themeforest.net/tutorials/vertical-centering-with-css/ The latter mentions the downside: Does not work in IE <8 ;)

Comment: @Pumbaa80 Thanks. This is exactly what I was looking for. Turn it into an answer and I'll re-accept it.

Comment: I only learned today that this works with checkboxes too :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This method is well-founded and documented in the CSS 2.1 specification in sections 10.6.4 and 10.6.5 (Absolutely positioned, non-replaced/replaced elements):

http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visudet.html#abs-non-replaced-height

The height of an absolutely positioned element is computed according to the following constraint:

```
   'top' + 'margin-top' + 'border-top-width' + 'padding-top' 
+ 'height' 
+ 'padding-bottom' + 'border-bottom-width' + 'margin-bottom' + 'bottom' 
= height of containing block
```

For an image, the height may be set to the intrinsic height of the image unless you constrain it otherwise.

If `margin-top` and `margin-bottom` use the `auto` value, then these margins are computed by assuming them to be equal, which allows the vertical centering to take place.

A similar logic applies to computed widths.

Unless you have large images that could create overflow conditions, this is a method that will work in CSS 2.1 compliant browsers.

Comment: @Kolink What? No. It's not hacky in the slightest